# How to write opencv function to find out if user is looking to the right of the camera, to the left of the camera, or straight towards the camera?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying (and struggling) to write an opencv function to find out if a user is looking to the right of the camera, to the left of the camera, or straight towards the camera?

Here's what I have already: I used Cascade Classifier to draw an ellipse around the face and squares to represent the eyes.

I basically have scoring functions that determine the best face array and best left array and best right eye array, since the cascade classifier returns several for each of the face and the 2 eyes.

```
import cv2
import glob


def draw(color_face, list_of_coordinates):
    print("the width of good eye:")
    print(list_of_coordinates[0][2])
    print("\n")
    print("the height of good eye:")
    print(list_of_coordinates[0][3])
    topleftcoordinate = (list_of_coordinates[0][0], list_of_coordinates[0][1])
    width_height = (list_of_coordinates[0][0]+list_of_coordinates[0][2],
                    list_of_coordinates[0][1]+list_of_coordinates[0][3])
    color = (0, 255, 255)
    thickness = 2
    cv2.rectangle(color_face, topleftcoordinate,
                  width_height, color, thickness)


eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

images = glob.glob('faces1/*.png')

for image in images[1:]:
    print("newimage\n")
    print(image)
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.085, 2)
   

    # draw ellipse
    i = 0
    greatest_width = 0
    greatest_height = 0
    good_x = 0
    good_y = 0

    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
     

        if(w > greatest_width):
            greatest_width = w
            greatest_height = h
            good_x = x
            good_y = y
       

        

 

        gray_face = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]  # this section includes only the face
        # x and y are the top left coordinate of the face
        color_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

      

        

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray_face, 1.085, 2)  # before was 1.05 and 4
        print("here is eyes line 143")
        print(eyes)
        best_left_eye = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        good_left_eyes = []
        for eye in eyes:
            

            x = eye[0]

            x = x + good_x
            print("x is")
            print(x)
            print("\n")
            y = eye[1]

            y = y + good_y
            print("y is")
            print(y)
            print("\n")

            width = eye[2]

            print("width is")
            print(width)
            print("\n")
            height = eye[3]

            print("height is")
            print(height)
            print("\n")

            if((y+height < good_y+greatest_height//2) and (y > good_y) and (x > good_x) and (x+width < good_x+greatest_width//2)):
                good_left_eyes.append(eye)

        smallest_difference_in_distance = 1000000
        smallest_difference_in_area = 1000000

        best_right_eye = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        good_right_eyes = []
        for eye in eyes:

            x = eye[0]
            x = x+good_x
            y = eye[1]
            y = y+good_y
            width = eye[2]
            height = eye[3]

           

           
            if((y+height < good_y+greatest_height//2) and (y > good_y) and (x > good_x+greatest_width//2) and (x+width < good_x + greatest_width)):
                good_right_eyes.append(eye)

    

        # draw a rectangle around eyes
        color = (0, 255, 255)
        thickness = 2

        

        for (eye_x, eye_y, eye_width, eye_height) in eyes:
            topleftcoordinate = (eye_x, eye_y)
            width_height = (eye_x+eye_width, eye_y+eye_height)
            cv2.rectangle(color_face, topleftcoordinate,
                          width_height, color, thickness)

       

        draw(color_face, good_left_eyes)



        draw(color_face, good_right_eyes)

        


       

    # this is a tuple containing the major and minor axes in that order for ellipse
    minor = (greatest_height*2)//4
    major = (greatest_height*1)//3  # greatest_width//3
    axes_length = (major, minor)
    # dividing the height by 2 will give a horizontal ellipse
    # dividing the width by 2 will give a vertical ellipse
    center_coordinates = good_x + greatest_width // 2, good_y + greatest_height // 2
    angle = 0  # ellipse rotation angle
    start = 0  # ellipse start drawing at this angle
    end = 359  # ellipse end drawing at this angle
    color = (0, 0, 100)
    thickness = 3
    cv2.ellipse(img, center_coordinates, axes_length,
                angle, start, end, color, thickness)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(10000)
    break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use facial landmarks recognizer such as Dlib's: https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/

Here's a simple example:

https://github.com/Twenkid/ComputerVision_Pyimagesearch_OpenCV_Dlib_OCR-Tesseract-DL/blob/e3457a8b6a5b8160d2fc382bca208122c8939815/pyimage/dlibface.py#L6

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2
 
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])
# load the input image, resize it, and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
# detect faces in the grayscale image
rects = detector(gray, 1)
# loop over the face detections
for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
    # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
    # array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
 
    # convert dlib's rectangle to a OpenCV-style bounding box
    # [i.e., (x, y, w, h)], then draw the face bounding box
    (x, y, w, h) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
 
    # show the face number
    cv2.putText(image, "Face #{}".format(i + 1), (x - 10, y - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
 
    # loop over the (x, y)-coordinates for the facial landmarks
    # and draw them on the image
    for (x, y) in shape:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
 
# show the output image with the face detections + facial landmarks
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

--shape-predictor is a path to the pretrained model from dlib.

Then once you have the face and the eyes, there's an ambiguity: should your recognize if the face is looking aside, but the gaze is looking to the other direction (that's unlikely maybe, but may confuse one of the solution, the chin direction has to be recognized, also it may cause the face to be semi-profile and the model could fail to discover the face). That "Yaw" of the faces, if the chin-direction is relevant, is measured e.g. in deepfake libs, such as Deepfacelab, but one has to dive into the code. If you wish to do that, one example:

https://github.com/Twenkid/DeepFaceLab-SAEHDBW/blob/65ffc57258cbe0372bafee4a574f122b747d6a7a/_internal/DeepFaceLab_SAEHDBW/samplelib/SampleProcessor.py#L50

Part of the preprocessing is computing facial landmarks and the orientation of the faces, the results are stored as metadata.

...

Without Deepfacelab:

If the faces are supposed to look only straight, you could search within the area of the eyes (contours closed by the landmarks 37-42, 43-48) for the locations of the brighter areas, the white of the eye.

One simple way is to scan through the long axis of the (coordinates of 37 to 40), you may divide the line in several segments and sum the brightness - you may convert it to grayscale or sum all colors.
That's how you'll estimate where the pupil is.

If the scanline/scanbar is brighter on the both sides than in the center (== if there's a darker spot in the middle, significantly lower brightness) - that's a straight gaze. If it's brighter only on one side and then it's only darker, near to the corner - it's a gaze to the direction of the darker side.